# How do calculate rotation of object to point towards point3

Tags: vector, rotation, trigonometry, maxscript

How do I find the rotation value of the teapot so when the new rotation value is applied, the teapot is pointing towards the sphere (point3) in the teapots own local space.

Here is what the starting scene looks like:
[image]

This is the goal I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

initial attempt:

```
delete objects
target = sphere pos:[20,20,20] radius:2
n = teapot radius:2 pos:[6,35,0]
rotate n (angleaxis -68.2351 [0.808965,0.587747,0.0113632])

dist = n.pos - target.pos
vec = normalize dist
upVecLocal = n.transform.row3 -- local up vector 
dp = dot vec upVecLocal
t = acos dp
newDir = cross upVecLocal dist

n.dir = newDir
toolMode.coordsys #local
select n
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you're trying to achieve, but I think the best solution is a non-scripting one: Add a Look At Constraint on the Teapot:

1. Select the Teapot
2. Go to the Motion tab (the wheel, 4th one from the left)
3. Select the Rotation button, then click the button above the tree view that includes the Transform, position, rotation and scale.
4. Select the sphere as the Look At Target

Now if you move the sphere it will rotate and follow.